# What does "the case today" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Does it refer to ***sadness and melancholia today***?

> Much of clinical and counselling psychology is devoted to managing
> negative affectivity and alleviating sadness. Yet, it seems that some
> degree of sadness and melancholia has been far more accepted in
> previous historical ages than is ***the case today***. From the
> classic philosophers through Shakespeare to the works of Chekhov,
> Ibsen, and the great novels of the 19th century, exploring the
> landscape of sadness, longing, and melacholia has long been considered
> ennobling. It is only in the last few decades that a veritable
> industry promoting the cult of positivity has managed to eliminate
> this earlier and more balanced view of human affectivity.

[The Social Psychology of Living Well](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=DipKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT225&lpg=PT225&dq=From%20the%20classic%20philosophers%20through%20Shakespeare%20to%20the%20works%20of%20Chekhov,%20Ibsen,%20and%20the%20great%20novels%20of%20the%2019th%20century,%20exploring%20the%20emotions%20of%20sadness,%20longing,%20and%20depression%20has%20long%20been%20considered%20instructive.&source=bl&ots=Q2v3wo0EJQ&sig=ACfU3U2jgfQrchVbV5rT7UfqT4v1diqzJw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQitXaj9vrAhUSiZQKHdFND_sQ6AEwB3oECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=From%20the%20classic%20philosophers%20through%20Shakespeare%20to%20the%20works%20of%20Chekhov%2C%20Ibsen%2C%20and%20the%20great%20novels%20of%20the%2019th%20century%2C%20exploring%20the%20emotions%20of%20sadness%2C%20longing%2C%20and%20depression%20has%20long%20been%20considered%20instructive.&f=false)

Comment: It refers to, "the degree of sadness and melancholia that is accepted today".

Answer (score 1):

> it seems that some degree of sadness and melancholia has been far more accepted in previous historical ages ***than is the case today***.

The bold part is a clause that could be re-written as

> *than it is accepted today (in our times)*.

Basically, ***is the case*** replaces the referent provided in the previous clause: *some degree of sadness and melancholia is accepted*. ***To be the case*** is a phrase:

> If you say that something is the case, you mean that it is true or correct.
>
> - Consumers had hoped the higher prices would mean more goods in stores. But that ***was not the case***. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-the-case))

Comment: Good answer. It is OED sense 6a of the noun "case" - ***An instance of a particular situation; an example of something occurring; a particular circumstance or state of affairs.**

Answer (score 0):

'The case today' refers to today's degree of acceptance of sadness and melancholia.